# How to find the border crossing time of a train in Europe? (Czech bureaucracy edition)

Tags: trains, europe

I'm traveling for work for my company in the Czech republic, and they allow me to take the train, but I need to specify the time that the train crosses each border. Ideally the location too, but that can be a bit vague.

The times want to be more accurate, but some approximation is inevitable.

For example, Trainline tells me that I can take a train from Prague to Zurich leaving at 6:38 and getting in at 17:23 with 3 changes.  That must cross from the Czech Republic of into Germany and from Germany to Switzerland, how can I find the times of those border crossings?

This information must be given in advance, before I have even booked a ticket. The employer is Czech.

I'm interested in a general strategy, or website to search on, not times specific to that trip.

Comment: This is a strange requirement (but there are a lot of them anyway for corporate or government expense reports!). I would just put the time of the last stop before or first stop after the border crossing or take the average (since the border officials if any would board the trains during this time). But it may be useful if you could inquire why an "accurate" border crossing time is required.

Comment: If it was an overnight train this would make more sense, to know the number of (part) days you spend abroad, perhaps for insurance purposes.  But unless there's some effect of the number of multiples of 24 hours, it shouldn't matter what exact time

Comment: If you search on bahn.de, you will find a list of "official" border crossings in the details of each connection. For the connection you mentioned, this would be Cheb and Schaffhausen. Other connections list a stop in Germany as border crossing, so this is not simply "the first stop outside Germany". Would your company be satisfied with such a statement?

Comment: Even before Schengen, it was commonplace for the Border Guards of both countries to get on at the last Station ; do the checks while the train is moving on to the first station of the other country. The longest wait is often when the locomotives are changed.

Comment: The accuracy asked by the form is +/-30mins. I will ask admin why they want this, but I'm not sure they will know either, travel admin is done by an agency.

Comment: @Sabine that sounds like a good solution.

Comment: Shortly after crossing a border in Europe, I usually get a text message on my phone that says 'welcome to country x'. If you get those too, the time of that message would maybe be close enough?

Comment: Do you need to know *in advance*? How will admin know if it is accurate to 30 mins? If they have to ask you, presumably they don't know. So make a reasonable estimate.

Comment: @TooTea yes likely, my employer is czech. Please do answer if you know something specific to the Czech system.

Comment: I can give a somewhat useful point for a crossing at Basel. You enter switzerland when then train leaves Basel badischer Bahnhof or you leave the train at Basel badischer Bahnhof.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes unfortuatly I need the information in advance. (before I even book the trains, which presents a whole additional issue with tickets selling out, but that's not the issue here)

Comment: I'd simply forward them the number of the train & website and tell them to figure this out for themselves since you, correctly, have no idea how to get this information and, if they are asking it, they are probably more accustomed to finding this out.

Comment: @SirHawrk It's operated by DB and just like the French parts of Basel SBB or Cornavin in Geneva, there are a lot of funny rules and agreements but isn't Basel Bad entirely on Swiss territory?

Comment: One additional issue is that night trains are not even really guaranteed to follow the same route and border check point every time.

Comment: @Relaxed yes it is. But it still has those rules. The border crossing is inside the Station building

Comment: @SirHawrk Sure but you're entering the country earlier, not when leaving the station. Think of it like an airport hall: You clearly are in the country (and subject to its laws) even if you haven't cleared immigration. Incidentally, in Switzerland, this border crossing only subsists for customs purposes, it's not a full-fledged border crossing anymore.

Comment: @Clumsycat Please note that currently the service between Prague and Germany is replaced by buses on some routes. At least the trains going through Pilsen are replaced by bus in Pilsen.

Comment: @Berend It's not a welcome to the country, but rather a welcome to the cellular network, informing you about the change in phone tariffs. And it's only dependent on network coverage, not to the actual border crossing.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It sounds like your employer needs this to calculate the correct reimbursement of travel expenses for this business trip. [Czech labour law](https://www.zakonyprolidi.cz/cs/2006-262#p170) lays out a notoriously complex set of rules on how to do that. (See for example this [nice writeup](https://www.finance.cz/dane-a-mzda/mzda/cestovni-nahrady/zahranicni-stravne/) in Czech.) In short, your employer has to pay you a fixed daily meal allowance (a.k.a. *per diem*) according to a country-specific rate set by the law (e.g. €50 for Germany). For each day of your trip, the country in which you spend the most time determines the applicable rate, and this is what you need the border crossing times for.

[Article 154](https://www.zakonyprolidi.cz/cs/2006-262#p154) of the Czech Labour Code specifies that time spent abroad is determined from the *time of border crossing as reported to the employer by the employee*. In case of flights, what matters is the departure time on the way out and the arrival time on the return journey:

> Dobou rozhodnou pro vznik práva zaměstnance na náhradu cestovních výdajů v cizí měně je doba přechodu státní hranice České republiky, kterou oznámí zaměstnanec zaměstnavateli, nebo doba odletu z České republiky a příletu do České republiky při letecké přepravě.

You can notice there's no notion of "scheduled time" in that paragraph, so strictly speaking these should be actual border crossing times, including delays and the like. However, opinions vary on how strictly to apply this in practice. The general consensus seems to be that it would be unreasonable for the employee to have to watch out for border posts and record the exact time they passed them, so unless you're travelling by car, you will typically be expected to report some officially listed border crossing time for your train or bus.

Many companies do as far as to disregard any delays altogether and insist on reporting crossing times exactly as they are in the timetable (even though this has no real support in the law). That's mostly because such companies don't trust their employees, so they want some sort of a "paper trail" instead. (As in, "we don't care your flight was three hours late, your boarding pass clearly says you departed at 12:00". Sadly, such an approach is disturbingly common among Czech employers.) Mainly bigger corporations also want you to report planned border crossing times for internal budgeting reasons (so they can pre-calculate the expected costs for your trip).

As far as international trains are concerned, there's always a specific border crossing point listed in the schedule with a particular time, and this is what most Czech employers expect you to report. You might have to use for example the Czech [idos.cz](https://idos.idnes.cz/vlaky/spojeni/) trip planner to see this information. A random example (yes, it is always in Czech even if you switch the website to English):
[image: example train schedule with a listed border crossing]

Finally, remember you typically don't need to worry much about accuracy. The only thing that matters is

- which foreign country you spend the most time in in any given day
- when only a part of a day is spent abroad, there are four bands for the meal allowance with cutoffs of 1/12/18 total hours abroad

So unless your itinerary puts you close to one of these boundaries, it doesn't matter at all whether you cross the border an hour earlier or later as the overall outcome won't be affected.

Comment: Three cheers for Czech bureaucracy. I can see how they created Kafka. Thanks, this is all the information I needed.

Comment: @Clumsycat You tell me. Having first worked in the Netherlands (a country otherwise renowned for its red tape), I still had a massive culture shock when I encountered Czech labour law. :-)

Comment: Interesting that for a flight, departure time is considered the border crossing time, while for a train, they need to know the actual (scheduled) crossing time, not the departure time. I guess that a modicum of reality crept into the flight times, since a flight between A & B can be routed any number of different ways in the air on different days...

Comment: @FreeMan The part on the train that is domestic is not covered by per-diem for traveling abroad. The rates for domestic trips are much lower. The requirements are given by the law, the accountants of the company did not invent it. The airplane travels are usually long enough, but train or car travels can be short ones where you go only to some town close to the border.

Comment: @FreeMan The law has been like this for decades, so before the Schengen area became a thing, you actually had a well defined border crossing that you couldn't miss. At the same time, nobody could reasonably expect you to sit on a plane carefully watching your GPS and a map to figure out when you are above a border. And that's even before you consider transatlantic flights. Enroute countries don't count anyway, so if OP flew from Prague to Zürich directly, Germany would have never entered the equation.

Comment: Great information — Czech Republic is not alone in these requirements, we have similar rules in Germany, making people to research border crossing times on their train journeys in order to fill out paperwork for a business trip.

Answer (score 14):

Just look at your booking information. Bahn.de for example list all the stops and times. You can either list the last stop in the exit country, the first stop in the entry country or split the difference based on distance to the border. In your case I would go with 9:36 for Czech to Germany (departure Cheb) and 16:47 (depart Schaffenhausen) for entry into Switzerland.

Personally I would push back on this a bit and ask what exactly this information is needed for. Depending on your mode of transportation this could be a lot of extra work and that work should be justified somehow. What would be the requirement if your took a plane? There is some time between departing Czech and entering Switzerland where you are not in any specific country at all.

Comment: Not to forget about notorious train delays. Fine that your train is **supposed** to leave at 16:47, but what if it's 30min or even 2hours late?

Comment: Yeah, the ALEX (the train from Prague to Munich) is often very late, and the time of border crossing varies widely. I am not sure how one could account for that in advance...

Comment: So far, this is the strategy I'm using. If @TooTea posts a Czech specific answer, I will redo my travel forms with that. It is a lot of extra work, but if I kick up a fuss I will be told to just fly. I'm keen not to fly for environmental reasons, so I will navigate the politics on this one.

Comment: You are paid per-diem money for the time you are abroad. The amount changes if it is more than 8 hours or more than 12 hours or more than 18 hours in a given day. It is governed by the law and it is a requirement of an employer to pay this money to the employee sent abroad. A different amount is payed for domestic travels. For airplane travels the law says one should consider the departure and the arrival time according to the schedule. I do not remember the exact formulation for trains.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава That explanation makes sense of this interest in border crossing times. And why they don't care when I'm flying. Thanks!

Comment: @infinitezero If you have to give the times in advance, you simply can't account for any delays. You can only give the expected times, since those are the only thing you can possibly know in advance (in most cases, a delay isn't known in advance). The best you can do is send the expected times and if a delay happens, notify the employer as soon as you know the actual crossing time (so probably once you're actually close to the border, if not across it).

Comment: That is correct, although many accountants do not like it and want various certificates of delays, the law does not requires them (I just checked) and it is the employee's signature on the final bill that signifies what the actual time of border crossing was. It is only significant if it changes the final amount anyway - as explained by Too Tea.

Answer (score 3):

The Interrail Rail Planner App shows between which stops the border crossing occurs. For most border crossings, the stops near the border are close enough to approximate the timing of the train crossing.

It is available [for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.eurail.railplanner) and [for IOS](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/rail-planner-eurail-interrail/id579547877).

Below an example showing the crossing tariff points Summerau (Gr) and Horni Dvoriste St.Hr on the railway between Linz, Austria and Ceske Budejovice. As you can see, the crossing is approximately at 20:00.

[image: Interrail Rail Planner Query]